# Get the Value of react redux in the child at the Component that call on React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I Have this Example of the code on my Container

```
import TopicDetail, {
  Props,
} from '../TopicDetail';

type ContainerProps = Partial<Props>;

function Topic(
  props: ContainerProps,
): React.ReactElement<Props> {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const topics = useSelector(getTopicReview);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTopicReviewRequest());
  }, []);
  // topics = { [topic1],[topic2] }

  return (
    <TopicDetail
      {...props}
      topicReview={topics}
    />
  );
}

export default Topic;
```

While the props of The Topic will be located on TopicDetail and that not having the problem.

The question is when I want to call this Topic in another Component called TopicHead, I want to get the value of the topics that located inside the Topic Component and I trying using the approach like below but it didn't work and the topics just returning an `undefined` value

```
// In Another Component
import Topic, {
  Props,
} from '../Topic';

function TopicHead(){
  var topics;
  <Topic {..props} topics{topics} />
  // topics = { [topic1],[topic2] }
};
```

Is there any possible way to get the value of it on TopicHead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to pass the props up using the `useState` hook and then making sure that each time `topics` change within the `Topic` component, the `setState` method for the parent gets called.

```
import TopicDetail, { Props } from '../TopicDetail';

type ContainerProps = Partial<Props> & {
  onChange: (value: any) => void
};

function Topic(
  props: ContainerProps,
): React.ReactElement<Props> {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const topics = useSelector(getTopicReview);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTopicReviewRequest());
  }, []);
  // topics = { [topic1],[topic2] }

  React.useEffect(() => props.onChange(topics), [topics])

  return (
    <TopicDetail
      {...props}
      topicReview={topics}
    />
  );
}

export default Topic;
```

And then the TopicHead component.

```
// In Another Component
import Topic, { Props } from '../Topic';

function TopicHead(){
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState();

  <Topic {..props} onChange={setTopics} />
  // topics = { [topic1],[topic2] }
};
```

I haven't been able to test this of course, but I hope you get the point of it even if it doesn't work exactly. Also, make sure that you handle `topics` in `TopicHead` with care, otherwise, it might cause excessive re-renders.

Comment: I do get your point here, Thank you. I'll update it to you once I tried this approach

Answer (score 0):

I guess `useDispatch` and `useSelector` are from `react-redux` and therefore you are using redux to store the topics.

Thus you can use the same selector in your `TopicHead`.

```
function TopicHead(){
  const topics = useSelector(getTopicReview); 

  <Topic {..props} topics={topics} />
  // topics = { [topic1],[topic2] }
};
```

**EDIT**

> I know this might be possible, But In my case on Topic, there is quite a lot of logic to get the final topic value.

I usually move all logic into the reducers, because they are easier to test. Thus I usually don't have the problem of how to access logic in another component.

Anyway, you can pass a state setter to the `Topic` component. So that the `Topic` can call this method if it's logic has computed a new value for the topic. E.g.

```
function TopicHead(){
   const [topic, setTopic] = useState(); 

  <Topic {..props} onTopicChanged={setTopic} />
};
```

> Also if I adding the useSelector in the TopicHead, there'll be double the redux calling, isn't it?

Yes, but it is just selecting a value from the state like `state.topics[0].name`, isn't it? Do you worry about performance issues? Selecting a value from the state is usually not a time consuming operation, because all values are already computed by the reducers. I said "usually" because you can break this pattern and do time consuming things in a selector, but I hope you don't.

Comment: I know this might be possible, But In my case on Topic, there is quite a lot of logic to get the final topic value. So I think that it's possible to just parse the final value from Topic into TopicHead. And Also if I adding the `useSelector` in the TopicHead, there'll be double the redux calling, isn't it? since I can't remove the `useSelector` call in the Topic